# Do people ever use a variable.php file?

Tags: php, function, variables, session, constants

As I'm learning PHP, a lot of scripts I write end up with a lot of variables.  I've gotten very used to using files such as functions.php and sessions.php in my includes folder.  What about variables?  Is it better to just create a bunch of variables on pages or to store them all in a single file?   If not - would a better option be a constants.php file?

Comment: Please, provide code examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends. When you install a program like WordPress it uses `wp-config.php` to essentially store variables & control WordPress install options in a separate file. Placing commonly used items in a separate file is a basic programming concept. The choice is based on your application’s usage and structure.

In general, when I code from scratch I place non-system specific variables in a file called `config.php` and then place local system specific variables in `local.php`.

`config.php` is application specific values that could—for all intents & purposes—never changes. But you would at least like to have the option to centrally control them.

`local.php` is strictly for local values like MySQL DB info, paths & URLs. Things idiosyncratic to the system the application is running on.

Comment: What if I have a bunch of variables such as $meat = chicken; and it is being used to be inserted into the database on a page?  Should that type of variable just be on the page?  (And I would not want $meat to equal anything else ever.)

Maybe I should download Wordpress and start looking at all the files on that.  Is it a convoluted structure or easy to see how things are put together?

Comment: Ok that makes sense.  I appreciate your answers.  I'll go ahead and download Wordpress.  A guy told me it might help me to "reverse engineer" already written code.  (Or something to that effect.)

Comment: A good way to learn best practices is to use a PHP Framework like CakePHP or Symfony 2. It requires good notions of OOP, MVC and namespaces tho

Answer (score 2):

It's best for readability and maintenance to have global values like db infos / facebook app id / website infos in one or more config files. Makes migrations and the such so much easier.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense.  So then those things will be readily accessible whenever I need them such as my functions or sessions, right?

Comment: yep I tend to group them together like common (required globally), back end (required globally in the back-end) , front end (required globally in the front-end)